# Does the expectation of the log of a gaussian cumulative distribution function with respect to to a gaussian distribution have an analytical solution?

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-distributions, expectation

I would like to know if the following has an analytical solution. If no such solution exists then I would like to know if there is an approximation which can be used instead.

$$\mathbb{E}_{N(a;\ m,\ \sigma ^2)}\left [\ln (\Phi(a))  \right ]$$

For extra info what I am trying to do is obtain gradients of this expression with respect to the parameters of the gaussian $m$ and $\sigma ^2$ so I want a symbolic expression which I can take derivatives of.

Comment: I have taken the liberty of changing the phrase "cumulative density function" to "cumulative distribution function". The word "cumulative" contradicts the word "density". There's no such thing as a cumulative density function.

Comment: What do you mean with an analytical solution? there is not equation there to solve. Do you mean an explicit formula? Have you written down the integral directly?

Comment: $$ \frac d {dm} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left( \log \int_{-\infty}^a \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-u^2/2} \,du \right)\, \frac 1 m e^{-\frac 1 2 \left( \dfrac{a-m} \sigma \right)^2} \, da $$  If not for that logarithm I'd say you'd start with the question of whether you can differentiate under the integral sign with respect to $m$ when the domain of integration is a half-plane bounded by that diagonal line. But then there's that logarithm. Note how $a$ appears in two places: as the upper bound of integration and also inside that exponential function. $\qquad$

Comment: @ Francisco sorry maybe I phrased the question badly, I am looking for the computed integral in terms of $m$ and $\sigma ^2$ and then the derivatives of that with respect to $m$ and $\sigma ^2$ (as Michael has kindly shown).

Comment: @ Michael, I think possibly we can transform with $a = m + \sigma v$ giving $\mathbb{E}_{N(v;\ 0,\ 1)}\left [\ln (\Phi(\ m +  \sigma v))  \right ]$ and then move the derivative inside the expectation. I think you can make progress that way but my calculus is too weak when I hit doing the actual integration

Comment: @Jack, $\ln \frac{1}{2}[1+erf(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}})]$, so yeah essentially

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood you correctly, you want the mean of $\ln F$ where $F$ is the cdf. In other words, $$\int_\mathbb{R}F'\ln Fdx=\int_0^1\ln FdF=[F\ln F-F]_0^1=-1.$$

Comment: LOL. How did we miss this? (+1)

Comment: hmm I don't think so. The cdf inside the expectation is just that of a standard normal whilst the expectation is with respect to a Gaussian with some other parameters, therefore the result should depend upon $m$ and $\sigma$. Or perhaps i am missing something..

Comment: @jp93k If that's what you wanted, it complicates matters, as there's no neat way to write $dF(ax+b)$ in terms of $dF(x)$.

Comment: The above proof does what the OP asked, and most elegantly too. If the OP intended otherwise, then that is a simple failure of the notation of the OP's question (in particular, failing to define notation).